# How to Load Image faster in Custom List view getting values from server?

Tags: android, json, listview, imageview, android-cardview

I am using Customized listview with image and text in card view method with help of volley.But sometimes it takes more time to load an image in the Image view, I have 15 to 20 list view campaigns images.Getting values from API on the server. How to fix this issue? If an alternative method is there tell me to fix this issue?[image: multiple list view screen]

Comment: Tweak your Server code and request only a smaller image size for your app.

Comment: campaign image size is 530 * 325.so I can't compress and can't change as small size, any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. I would recommend to use [recyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) in stead of listView
2. Try [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)
3. Compress/reduce size of image. May be you can try [Photoshop](http://www.adobe.com/sea/products/photoshop.html) or [watch how to optimize image on Android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_LpCi6DQME) E.g. reduce color.
4. Cache image / pre-download
5. Try to verify the server response speed if it is low then try another server or cloud.
6. Send the smallest images for each screen dpi.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library to easily load image.

> A powerful image downloading and caching library for Android

Also checkout [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library -

> An image loading and caching library for Android focused on smooth
>   scrolling.